# shiny - omitting a userinput with filter when "All" is selected

Tags: r, shiny

In the Ui.R i have some input selects, of which Location is one, I would like to be able to omit the same if "All" is selected,

```
selectInput('Location', 'Location', choices = c("All", unique(sampleData$Location)), selected = "All"),
```

I tried using reactive if else, but there is an error which says - 
**"Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types."**

I am new to shiny, can I use inpLocation that way?
Any help is appreciated.

Here's my entire code -

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
load("sample_Data.rdata")
nms <- names(sample_Data)

ui <- (pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Demo"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('sex', 'Sex', choices = unique(sample_Data$sex), selected = "F"),
    selectInput('Location', 'Location', choices = c("All", unique(sample_Data$Location)), selected = "All"),
    selectInput('color1', 'Color1', choices = c('None', nms), selected = "region"),
    selectInput('color2', 'Color2', choices = c('None', nms), selected = "species")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, plotlyOutput("p1"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12, plotlyOutput("p2"))
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  nms <- row.names(sample_Data)
    dataset <- reactive({
      inpLocation <- reactive({
        if(input$Location == "All"){
          sample_Data$Location
        }else{
          input$Location
        }})

      sample_Data %>%
        filter(sex %in% input$sex, inpLocation())
    })

  output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
    p<-qplot(year,N,data=dataset(),color=species)
    if (input$color1 != 'None') p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color1)
    p<-ggplotly(p)
    p
  })

  output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
    p<-qplot(region,N,data=dataset(),color=species)
    if (input$color2 != 'None') p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color2)
    p <- ggplotly(p)
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(display.mode = "showcase"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the second `reactive` inside of the first `reactive` call. Inside the outer `reactive` it will already be updated whenever the `input$Location` is changed.

```
dataset <- reactive({
  if(input$Location == "All"){
    inpLocation <- sample_Data$Location
  }else{
    inpLocation <- input$Location
  }
  sample_Data %>%
    filter(sex %in% input$sex, 
           Location %in% inpLocation)
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for clarifying that, I was wondering what is the use of "inpLocation()" in the last statement then? 
With your suggestion, it's giving me an error **"no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"**

Comment: I have edited my answer. I accidentally assigned the location to dataset when I should have assigned it to inpLocation. Hopefully it will work now

Comment: That solves it I believe, thanks a bunch. Just wondering if using "sample_Data$Location" will give me the whole column.. ?

Comment: yes, it will give you a vector with all of the values. You can confirm this by typing `sample_Data$Location` into your console (assuming you have `sample_Data` loaded into your global environment).